# Journey filter logic for decision split based on month range after birthdate (mm/dd/yyyy)

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, criteria-filter

I am looking for help with an age based journey. The journey has a decision split that needs the proper filter logic using the birthdate (ex. 12/21/1983) field that includes the year. The entry source is coming over from a campaign as Salesforce Data that people aging to 49-50 are entered into.

This journey is for people turning 50. Before turning 50 they start the journey at 49. If the person is months over 49 the decision split would put them on the correct decision path.

The problem is doing a date range based off of after an anniversary, with what is given as filter criteria of a decision split. You can not combine "is anniversary of" with "is on or after" that I am aware of, and the year in the birthdate field would mess with only having "is on or after."

**Decision Splits:**
Email 1 - Full Journey - age 49 (day of and greater than 60 days)
Email 2 - Rest of Journey - age 49.2 (greater than 60, less than 120 days)
Email 3 - Rest of Journey - age 49.4 (greater than 120 less than 180 days)
Email 4 - Birthday - 
I would like to send this on the day of, I was hoping to use the "wait by attribute" activity in the journey, but anniversary is not a choice since the birthdate includes the year. If the email is not sent the day of that's ok, as long as it's ballpark because it will play off the time duration.
Email 5 - age 50.2 (2 months after email 4/Birthday).

Any ideas or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options for the journey:

**Option 1:** *Apply the same wait period for everyone.*

If you have your emails 1 through 4 based on the age of 49 and months after 49, you can use a general wait period that applies to everyone. After email 3, wait 7 months. Obviously email 4 would not likely send on the subscribers’ actual birthday.

**Option 2:** *Split the one journey into two journeys.*

Keep what you have above for Journey 1, with the exception of the birthday email. For the birthday email, use the anniversary decision split. The pros of this is that the email is sent on the actual birthday. The cons is that it is two journeys to manage and a separate campaign in CRM.

**Option 3:** *Add a process to parse the birthday month and day.*

You can query the synchronized data extension and enter the subscriber exactly on their 49th birthday and use the *Wait Until Attribute* for their 50th birthday. The caveat is that you’ll need to use a data extension as the journey entry event instead of Salesforce Data so there will be a maximum of 1 hour delay to enter the journey (Automation Studio hourly interval).

If the email sends aren’t time sensitive as in needing to be real time, option 3 might be best.

Comment: I appreciate your comments Jackson. The question was meant more for using Birthdate for a decision split filter.

The idea is to insert members if they are a specific age into the journey at different parts. If they are 49.2, they wouldn't get the first email, but the second. I've came to the conclusion that the best way to do this is to add an age logic field in Sales Cloud which is a number field (ex. 49.2) instead of date, and that way I can use greater than, less than, and in between, as part of the decision split.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend breaking this into 2 parts.
1 - Journey -- 
 For this, the easiest route is to set up a field that stores the age as a number.  This will allow you to do decision splits based on that field.
 The other option is to run a SQL that stores the birthdate with the current year so that you can use the wait until field.  Please note - the wait until evaluates the moment it reaches that step.  You can not change the value once it is already in that step.

2 - Automation --
 I would break out the actual Birthday email out to its own automation.  That way you have confidence that it went out on the correct day.